# Modificar If en una API que estoy haciendo

Tags: php, json, api

Que tal amigos espero se encuentren de lo mejor estoy haciendo una API la cual permita subir datos a través de ella, si inserta los datos que requiero pero me he topado con un problema el cual no puedo salir de ahi

Tengo el siguiente formulario.php el cual me funciona bien pero lo que requiero es que no necesito el **input imagen**

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="Cliente" placeholder="Nombre Cliente">
    <input type="text" name="rfc" placeholder="RFC">
    <input type="text" name="moneda" placeholder="Tipo de Moneda">
    <input type="text" name="mercancia" placeholder="Nueva o Usada">
    <input type="text" name="importe" placeholder="Importe Asegurado">
    <input type="text" name="TipoOperacion" placeholder="Bien Asegurado">
    <input type="datetime-local" name="FechaAlta" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i');?>">
    <input type="file" name="imagen" placeholder="">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

A lo que mi problema entra en esta parte, como pudiera quedar el segundo if para que en vez de la imagen sea algún otro campo o sea opcional la imagen y no obligatoria, ya que así como esta sino agrego una imagen no me inserta datos

```
if(isset($_POST['Cliente'])){
    if($api->subirImagen($_FILES['imagen'])){
        $item = array(
            'Cliente' => $_POST['Cliente'],
            'rfc' => $_POST['rfc'],
            'moneda' => $_POST['moneda'],
            'mercancia' => $_POST['mercancia'],
            'importe' => $_POST['importe'],
            'TipoOperacion' => $_POST['TipoOperacion'],
            'FechaAlta' => $_POST['FechaAlta'],
            'imagen' => $api->getImagen()
        );
        $api->add($item);
    }else{
        $api->error('Error con el archivo: ' . $api->getError());
    }
}else{
    $api->error('Error al llamar a la API');
}
```

Aqui esta la funcion de **subirImagen**, lo que hace es que guarda la imagen en una carpeta llamada imagenes la cual no debe de pesar mas de 5 megas, valida si es jpg o png y si no lo es no te permite insertar informacion en la base de datos hasta que cumplas con los requisitos de la imagen

Pero la verdad ya no me interesa subir una imagen pero si no la pongo forzosamente no me guarda nada, pero ya intente modificar el segundo **IF subirImagen**

```
function subirImagen($file){
    $directorio = "imagenes/";
    $this->imagen = basename($file["name"]);
    $archivo = $directorio . basename($file["name"]);
    $tipoArchivo = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // valida que es imagen
    $checarSiImagen = getimagesize($file["tmp_name"]);
    if($checarSiImagen != false){
        //validando tamaño del archivo
        $size = $file["size"];
        if($size > 500000){
            $this->error = "El archivo tiene que ser menor a 500kb";
            return false;
        }else{
            //validar tipo de imagen
            if($tipoArchivo == "jpg" || $tipoArchivo == "jpeg" || $tipoArchivo == "png"){
                // se validó el archivo correctamente
                if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $archivo)){
                    //echo "El archivo se subió correctamente";
                    return true;
                }else{
                    $this->error = "Hubo un error en la subida del archivo";
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                $this->error = "Solo se admiten archivos jpg/jpeg/png";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $this->error = "El documento no es una imagen";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte mejor falta información: ¿qué hace esta función: `subirImagen()`? ¿cuando no haya imagen, qué tiene que insertarse por defecto, otra imagen?

Comment: Que tal @A.Cedano un gusto volver a leerte, modifique mi pregunta y agregue la funcion que mencionas, no quiero insertar una imagen si es posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te interesa subir ninguna imagen entonces:

## 1. En el formulario

Quita el `input` que recoge la imagen. Observa que también he quitado al formulario el `enctype="multipart/form-data"` el cual debe ponerse en aquellos formularios por medio de los cuales mandas archivos adjuntos. Dado que no enviarás la imagen lo he quitado, dejándolo así:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Cliente" placeholder="Nombre Cliente">
    <input type="text" name="rfc" placeholder="RFC">
    <input type="text" name="moneda" placeholder="Tipo de Moneda">
    <input type="text" name="mercancia" placeholder="Nueva o Usada">
    <input type="text" name="importe" placeholder="Importe Asegurado">
    <input type="text" name="TipoOperacion" placeholder="Bien Asegurado">
    <input type="datetime-local" name="FechaAlta" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i');?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

## 2. En el servidor

Quita todos los condicionales relativos a la imagen, así como la llamada a la función. Además, lo que construyes como `$item` es lo mismo que ya tienes en `$_POST`, ya que `$_POST` no es otra cosa que un array exactamente igual que el que estás creando. Eso significa que puedes pasar directamente `$_POST` como parámetro al método `add()`.

El código quedaría así:

```
if(isset($_POST['Cliente'])){
        $api->add($_POST);
}else{
    $api->error('Error al llamar a la API');
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano si me funciono